# Random Forest in RankLib

Tags: random-forest, ranking

I am building a LETOR model using Random Forest with RankLib. As we know that the Random Forest gets better with higher number of trees, I got a totally different observation in my case. The performance of the model peak at 50 trees and it started to decrease onwards. I think RankLib is using MART to build the ensemble trees with each bags, but not sure how it is related to my observation.